# how to use capacitor plugin in web worker

Tags: ionic-framework, web-worker, ionic-native, capacitor, ionic5

I've added a web worker to my Ionic/React app.
It's a separate typescript codebase and bundled to `/assets/dist/worker.js`

To reproduce the setup, you could use this minimal example web worker:

```
import {v4} from 'uuid'

console.log('worker running');
onmessage=(e)=>{
    console.log('received message');
    postMessage(v4());
}
```

give it its own `tsconfig.json` with  `"lib": ["WebWorker", "WebWorker.ImportScripts"],` and bundle it with the bundler of your choice.

Make sure the bundled javascript is hosted under /assets and you can use it to create a web worker like this:

```
const myWorker = new Worker('assets/dist/worker.js');

export default function App(){
  const [v4, setV4] = useState("waiting for worker");
  myWorker.postMessage('go');
  myWorker.onmessage=(e)=>{
    setV4(e.data);
  }
  return (
  <IonApp>
    <p>{v4}</p>
  </IonApp>
)};
```

So far this works nicely. But it's not able to access capacitor plugins.
I would like to use the webworker to offload some heavy calculations and they include calls to custom native code. This native code is accessible via a capacitor plugin. But any capacitor plugin import creates an error message. Add the following code to the worker:

```
import {Plugins} from '@capacitor/core';

const {Device} = Plugins;
```

and it throws:

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

**Update:**
Tried a hacky workaround:

```
(<any> self).window = self;  // <------ here
import {v4} from 'uuid'
import {Plugins} from '@capacitor/core';

const {CustomNativePlugin} = Plugins;

console.log('worker running');
onmessage=(e)=>{
    console.log(CustomNativePlugin.customCall());
    postMessage(v4());
}
```

This creates a new error message:

```
Uncaught (in promise) CustomNativePlugin does not have web implementation.
```

Comment: So if the plugins are using "window" objects or other things that are not normally accessible within the context of web workers you will get this error. I guess depending on the plugin you could in theory modify it and prevent use of "window".

Comment: It's my own plugin. I know that it doesn't need window or dom. I think this window access has to do with how capacitor wires things up behind the scenes. Maybe some plugin registry on the global window or something like that. And this I would like to avoid

Comment: ah makes sense. You are right Capacitor does hook plugin APIs via window object. I wonder if you could create issue/feature request for them to consider non-window environments such as workers. Stupid question:) - what if inside worker you create "window" and assign it with "self"?:)

Answer (score 3):

Long shot in the dark... but if the comments under you question are right and `window` is indeed only used as a global object to wire the plugins, and if nothing else from `window` that is unavailable in the Worker scope is used, then you can just do

```
self.window = self;
```

At the beginning of your Worker script.

Comment: hahaha, nice idea :) It has strange results: The plugin object exists and can be imported, but calling any method raises a new exception: Uncaught (in promise) CustomNativePlugin does not have web implementation.

Comment: @lhk they must be looking at other properties on the window object then... Probably they need it, in which case, there isn't much you can do apart from asking the devs to rewrite it without this dependency.

Comment: It almost worked for me for the Filesystem plugin, everything works but inside the web worker Capacitor thinks we're not running on a native platform and fallbacks to the web implementation